# 'text must be a unicode or bytes'

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a 2d platforming game in python and have managed to get everything to work apart from displaying vital attributes such as player health.

I have successfully extracted the player's health, however when I try to display it, I am getting the error in the title.

This is the code I am using to display it:

```
localplayerhealth=player.gethealth()

healthmessage=('HEALTH: ',localplayerhealth,'%')

messagedisplay(healthmessage,BLACK,500,600, 30, 30, 'mediumfont')
```

localplayerhealth is a integer data type. I have tried many ways to get this to work, but for some reason they do not work.

Full traceback:

```
loop(gameclass,s,ishost,received)
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\Year13CA\Base.py", line 579, in loop
    player.updateposition(True,False)
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\Year13CA\PlayerClasses.py", line 249, in updateposition
    playerhealth=messagedisplay(self.health,BLACK,500,500, 30, 30, 'smallfont')
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\Year13CA\Shared.py", line 22, in messagedisplay
    surface, rectangle = textobject(message,colour,font)  #assigns both the variables of surface and rectangle to the output of the subroutine called with the imported parameters.
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\Year13CA\Shared.py", line 10, in textobject
    textSurface = smallfont.render(text, True, colour)
TypeError: text must be a unicode or bytes
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the full and exact error message, not just the approximation that you remember of it

Comment: Going out on a limb here, but I'm assuming the first argument to `messagedisplay` must be unicode or bytes, but you are passing it a `tuple`, i.e. the `tuple` you created with `healthmessage`. Perhaps try passing a string?

Comment: Maybe try `healthmessage=('HEALTH: {} %'.format(localplayerhealth))`? But, as others have said, you should include a full traceback.

Comment: does this does it ? `healthmessage='HEALTH: %s%%' % localplayerhealth`

Comment: @eric Trackback has been added. It is the exact error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to construct a string to be displayed you have to provide proper formatting. Right now you are creating a tuple:

```
>>> localplayerhealth=1
>>> 'HEALTH: ',localplayerhealth,'%'
('HEALTH: ', 1, '%')
```

I guess that you need a string:

```
>>> to_display = "HEALTH: {}%".format(localplayerhealth)
>>> to_display
'HEALTH: 1%'
```